# Function of $ in the given Haskell line

Tags: haskell

Can anybody tell me the function of `$` in following Haskell line.
$$ if for the last line but the function of `$`?

```
  concat $ replicate 3 "12345"
```

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-

Comment: Also https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%24 and http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%24

Comment: The marked duplicate actually has more information than you asked for, but lots of good answers.

Answer (score 5):

`$` is just a low precedence version of function application, i.e. `a $ b` is the same as `a b`.

It is commonly used to remove the need for parentheses, e.g.:

```
concat $ replicate 3 "12345"
```

is the same as:

```
concat (replicate 3 "12345")
```

Also, instead of having to write:

```
putStrLn ("hello " ++ name ++ "!")
```

you'll often see:

```
putStrLn $ "hello " ++ name ++ "!"
```